# stargazer notes not appearing at all

Tags: r, latex, stargazer

```
library(stargazer)
```

I'm trying to use the notes argument with stargazer, but its apparently not working. Here's code adapted from a previous stack overflow stargazer question:

```
stargazer(mtcars, notes=c("A very very long note that I would like to put below the table,",
                     "but currently runs off the side of the page",
                     "when I compile my document.",
                     "How do I get this to wrap into paragraph form?"))
```

When I compile my document, the note does not appear at all.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; when I compile the LaTeX output from your code, the note does not run off the page.

Comment: The note wasn't appearing at all for me - this is what my question was about

Comment: Hmm. I edited your question to clarify it some, but I'd be curious about more detail about how you're compiling the resulting latex: Sweave, knitr, copy+paste into a tex document...? Because as I said, when I simply take the LaTeX output from your exact code, and copy+paste it into a tex file it compiles just fine.

Comment: @luciano -- If the question is about *compiling*, not *wrapping*, then isn't this a LaTeX question? Please post what exactly you're getting from `stargazer` (and what you're trying to compile). Also, please make sure that you have the updated version of `stargazer`. It's under active development and my past problems have been solved by updating.

Comment: thanks updating to stargazer 5.0 solved it

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the note's multicolumn alignment (I guess the default is `l`) to `p{\linewidth}`. This isn't an option (only `clr`), but you can do the following.

- use `gsub` to replace the `{l}` with `{p{\linewidth}}`
- undo the side effects of `gsub` with `cat(, sep="\n")`

The following works for me.

```
cat(gsub("\\{l\\}", "{p{\\\\linewidth}}", stargazer(mtcars, notes="A very very long note that I would like to put below the table, but currently runs off the side of the page when I compile my document. How do I get this to wrap into paragraph form?")), sep="\n")
```